# Error when load library of zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I using library of Zend Framework and code php (no using struct zend, only use library of zend framework), when I load library of zend is error:

```
Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'Zend/Search/Lucene/Storage/File/Filesystem.php' 
(include_path='.;C:\php\pear;C:\wamp\www\Zend') in C:\wamp\www\...\Zend\Search\Lucene\Storage\Directory\Filesystem.php on line 349
```

I put library of Zend in C:\wamp\www\Zend
I call library of Zend in code php here:

```
ini_set("include_path", ini_get("include_path") . ";C:\\wamp\\www\\Zend");
require_once 'Zend/Search/Lucene.php';
```

How to load library of zend in this case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing:

```
ini_set("include_path", ini_get("include_path") . ";C:\\wamp\\www\\Zend");
```

to

```
ini_set("include_path", ini_get("include_path") . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'C:\\wamp\\www');
```

Since all of the Zend Framework files are included with the `Zend` directory leading the file names (i.e. `require_once 'Zend/Search/Lucene.php';` your include path should include the path where the `Zend` directory is, but should not add the `Zend` folder itself to the `include_path`.

---

Consider `require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';` with the following include paths:

`C:\\wamp\\www\\Zend`; resolves to `require_once 'C:\\wamp\\www\\Zend\\Zend\Loader.php';` (wrong)

`C:\\wamp\\www`, resolves to `require_once 'C:\\wamp\\www\\Zend\Loader.php';` (correct)